# Why doesn't this expression in Bash need string escaping?

Tags: bash, escaping

Why doesn't this expression need string escaping?

```
"$(dirname "${0}")"
```

It seems to me that the expression should actually be this instead:

```
"$(dirname \"${0}\")"
```

But, I believe the first expression still works without the \" (s) in the above version.

Why is that?

Comment: That is the magic behind the `$()` operator. If you used `\`\`` it would be different.

Comment: See [Unix.SE: Quoting within $(command substitution) in Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118433/quoting-within-command-substitution-in-bash)

Answer (score 2):

As per `man bash`:

> Bash performs the expansion by executing command in a subshell environment and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the
>          command, with any trailing newlines deleted.

And later:

> When using the `$(command)` form, all characters between the parentheses make up the command; **none are treated specially**.

> If the substitution appears **within double quotes**, word splitting and pathname expansion are not performed on the results.

So embedded quotes are not evaluated at the same time in same shell.

- All characters between the parentheses are evaluated in a subshell environment
- Optional outer quotes are there to prevent *word splitting* and *pathname expansion*.

Answer (score 1):

`$(...)` starts a new quoting context. The command substitution

```
$(dirname "${0}")
```

is evaluated first. The resulting output, not the command itself, is quoted by the outer quotes.

(I'm not *entirely* sure how `"$(dirname \"${0}\")"` is treated. It appears that some form of quote removal occurs before the command is parsed.)